# Get the values of different SQL access records into 1

Tags: php, sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm new here and I wanted to get some help solving an Access SQL data merging problem.

Actually I would like to turn this

```
Customer    Comment 
James        Good
James        Bad
James        Good
James        Ugly
```

into this :

```
Customer    Comments
James       Good, Bad, Good, Ugly
```

I need To concatenate all the comments of the same customer into one field without VBA because I'm executing the query with PHP

Thanks

Comment: There is a rather nasty way of doing this.  How large is your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I know how to get the Comments concatenated properly, but I'm not sure how to pull the customer.  I'm also not sure if this will work in Access, because Access doesn't support stored procs.

```
DECLARE @Comments VARCHAR(8000)  
SELECT @Comments = COALESCE(@Comments + ', ', '') + Comments FROM Customers
```

I'm guessing you'll have to do this for more than one customer, but all I can think to do is use a CURSOR for each customer, but I don't know if Access supports cursors at the moment.

```
DECLARE @Comments VARCHAR(8000)  
SELECT @Comments = COALESCE(@Comments + ', ', '') + Comments 
FROM Customers
WHERE Customer = @Customer (i.e. James, from the cursor)
```

Honestly, I think you're stuck doing this in PHP.

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY Customer, Comment
```

Then simply loop through the recordset and when the Customer changes, reset the Comments variable for the next customer.

Comment: No DECLARE or COALESCE in MS Access SQL.

Comment: @HansUp - that's what I was afraid of... Maybe port the Access table to Microsoft FREE version of SQL?

Comment: OK.  I was thinking any db which could do the concatenation before sending the data on to PHP.  If he's locked into Access for any reason, the last part of your answer looks good to me ... but I don't actually use PHP.  :-)

Comment: I'm doing it with PHP :) thnaks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to load all the matching rows from the database and concatenate them in PHP.

You can get Access to do this, though inefficiently, using a custom function:

```
Public Function CommentsForCustomer(Customer As String)
   Dim sql As String
   sql = "select [Comment] from Comments where Customer = '" & Customer & "'"

   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
   rs.Open sql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenSnapshot

   Dim text As String
   text = ""
   Do Until rs.EOF
       If Len(text) > 0 Then
           text = text & ", "
       End If
       text = text & rs.Fields("Comment")
       rs.MoveNext
   Loop
   rs.Close

   CommentsForCustomer = text
End Function
```

Then include the expression `CommentsForCustomer([Customer])` in your query.

Comment: He's using PHP to retrieve data from Access.  Access itself (MSACCESS.EXE) is not running, which means his query can't use a user-defined function.